# SQL statement to update a field only if the value is greater than the current one

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, jdbc, sql-update

So far, I have this statement:

`String query = "UPDATE Score SET Points = "+scorecard[TOTAL][i]+" WHERE Name = "+players[i].getName()+" AND Lastname = "+players[i].getLastName()";`

Any idea how I should go about it? I saw somewhere to use the `CASE WHEN` syntax but couldn't make it work.

Comment: `UPDATE Score SET ...` not `INSERT INTO Score SET ...`

Comment: Yeah, sorry fixed that. I copied a not-finished piece of code

Comment: Please don't concatenate values into a query string, use a prepared statement with placeholders instead. Your current code is open to sql injection, and can lead to hard to diagnose problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd want

```
update score set points = ? where
      name = ? and lastname = ?
      and points < ?
```

As SQL. And please use a PreparedStatement.

```
try(PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("update score set " + 
     " points = ? where name = ? and lastname = ? and points < ?") {
  ps.setInt(1, scorecard[TOTAL][i]);
  ps.setString(2, players[i].getName());
  ps.setString(3, players[i].getLastName());
  ps.setInt(4, scorecard[TOTAL][i]);
  ps.executeUpdate(); 
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error, which is what I was getting before:
`java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "Points": syntax error)`

Comment: Share your table definition?

Comment: `CREATE TABLE "Score" ("Name" CHAR NOT NULL , "Lastname" CHAR NOT NULL , "Age" INTEGER, "Points" INTEGER DEFAULT 0, PRIMARY KEY ("Name", "Lastname"))`. Thanks for taking the time to help!

Comment: Then try \"Points\" as column name (both times) - same for \"Lastname\" and \"Name\"

Comment: Same error except I get two more quotation marks around `"Points"`. Should I post my code maybe?

Comment: The query is missing an `and` before `points < ?`. That's the cause for the syntax error.

Comment: Thats right - andnwas missing. Thanks for pointing it out :-)

Comment: Thanks! Though I also made it work using MAX(col, value)